# What does そっくり mean in this context?

Tags: translation, meaning, manga

> [超]{スーパー}サイヤ[人]{じん}になったオレと**そっくり**だ...

According to dictionaries, "そっくり" can mean "exactly". So could this mean, "You are exactly [as powerful] as I am as a Super Saiyan"?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The best translation of そっくり is "the spitting image of". So the person he's talking to should probably look a lot like him when he was a super Saiyan.

Comment: Is there any way to translate it as "exactly" or "entirely"? Would that not make grammatical sense?

Comment: @metal Which dictionary did you use? そっくり meaning "entirely" is an adverb and そっくり meaning "as like as two peas" is a na-adjective. In your example そっくり is clearly used as a na-adjective.

Comment: If you use "exactly" you would still need something else as well, such as "alike".

Comment: @naruto Ah I see, my mistake. I used this dictionary: https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/amp/そっくり                               One of the definitions are "be just [exactly] like somebody", so I'm wondering if this always refer to appearance. This sample sentence also uses the word to describe sounding like someone: https://www.tanoshiijapanese.com/dictionary/sentence_details.cfm?sentence_id=167339&j=そっくり

Comment: @metal Physical appearance is the most common resemblance that そっくり refers to, but indeed, other characteristics could also be compared. Here's a thesaurus entry to back that up. https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/thsrs/16987/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%9D%E3%81%A3%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8A/

Comment: @Leebo Would that mean it's possible そっくり refers to "identical power" in this context? Or would it be spelled out more clearly?

Comment: Thank you for the additional informations. According to the context, it could be physical resemblance or any other criterion, indeed, as @Leebo said. So I think you can say they refer to identical power here.

Comment: @N Gillian Thank you for the help N Gillain